# Moving object after creation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to move UIImageView object after it is created, but seem to be having problems with accomplishing this. The actual creation of the image is working fine. This is the code that I have so far:

```
    //SPAWNING RANDOM OBJECTS


    -(IBAction)spawn{

    spawn = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(spawnMechanism)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
}
-(IBAction)spawnMove{

    spawnMove = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(spawnMoveMechanism)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}




-(UIImageView *)spawnMoveMechanism:(UIImageView *)spawnGood{

    spawnGood.center =CGPointMake(spawnGood.center.x, spawnGood.center.y+100);
    NSLog(@"spawnMoveMechanism accomplished");
    return spawnGood;
}

-(void)spawnMechanism{
    timeSinceLastSpawn++;

    if(timeSinceLastSpawn >= 3)
    {
        if( arc4random() % 10 < 7 ){


            UIImageView *spawnGood;

            spawnGood=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % 700, 50, 70,70)];
            UIImage *image;
            image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"friendly-01"];
            [spawnGood setImage:image];
            [self.view addSubview:spawnGood];
             NSLog(@"spawnGood spawned");
            [self spawnMoveMechanism]; 





        }
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to suggest a solution to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adjusting your code so your change of position (and required graphics UI change) happens on the main thread.

Comment: I have tried that, but the object only moves downwards once by 100 and stops?

Comment: Well, you know you're moving it now - put a breakpoint in the first line of spawnMoveMechanism and watch the value of spawnGood.center as you step through it.

Comment: I now seem to be getting this error: "-[FIVESContentViewController spawnMoveMechanism]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98862e0"